# Recursive python generators: why does the yield need to be iterated over?

Tags: python, generator

A good exercise to test one's understanding of recursion is to write a function that generates all permutations of a string:

```
def get_perms(to_go, so_far=''):
    if not to_go:
        return [so_far]
    else:
        ret = []
        for i in range(len(to_go)):
            ret += get_perms(to_go[:i] + to_go[i+1:], so_far + to_go[i])
    return ret
```

This code is fine, but we can significantly improve the efficiency from a memory standpoint by using a generator:

```
def perms_generator(to_go, so_far=''):
    if not to_go:
        yield so_far
    else:
        for i in range(len(to_go)):
            for perm in perms_generator(to_go[:i] + to_go[i+1:], so_far + to_go[i]):
                yield perm
```

(Note: the last `for` loop can also be replaced with `yield from` in python 3.3)

My question: why do we need to iterate over the results of each recursive call? I know that `yield` returns a generator, but from the statement `yield so_far` it would seem as though we're getting a string, and not something we would need to iterate over. Rather, it would seem as though we could replace

```
for perm in perms_generator(to_go[:i] + to_go[i+1:], so_far + to_go[i]):
    yield perm
```

with

```
yield perms_generator(to_go[:i] + to_go[i+1:], so_far + to_go[i])
```

Thank you. Please let me know if the title is unclear. I have a feeling the content of this question is related to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126845/generators-and-yield-statement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `return` and `yield` is that the former just returns a value. The latter means "wrap the value in a generator and then return the generator."

So in all cases, the function `perms_generator()` returns a generator.

The expression `yield perms_generator()` again would wrap the result of `perms_generator()` in a generator, giving you a generator of a generator. That would mean the function would return different things; sometimes, it would be a simple generator and sometimes nested generators. That would be very confusing for the consumer of your code.

Answer (score 3):

Remember, any function using `yield` does not *return* those values to the caller. Instead a *generator object* is returned and the code itself is instead paused until you iterate over the generator. Each time a `yield` is encountered, the code is paused again:

```
>>> def pausing_generator():
...     print 'Top of the generator'
...     yield 1
...     print 'In the middle'
...     yield 2
...     print 'At the end'
... 
>>> gen = pausing_generator()
>>> gen
<generator object pausing_generator at 0x1081e0d70>
>>> next(gen)
Top of the generator
1
>>> next(gen)
In the middle
2
>>> next(gen)
At the end
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Calling the `pausing_generator()` function returned a `generator object`. Only iterating (using the `next()` function here) runs the actual code in the function, but pausing execution each time a `yield` is encountered.

Your `perms_generator` function returns a such a generator object, and a recursive call would *still* return a generator object. You could `yield` the whole generator object, but then you are producing a generator that produces a generator, etc. until you come to the inner-most generator.

You can visualise this with `print` statements:

```
>>> def countdown(i):
...     if not i:
...         return
...     yield i
...     recursive_result = countdown(i - 1)
...     print i, recursive_result
...     for recursive_elem in recursive_result:
...         yield recursive_elem
... 
>>> for i in countdown(5):
...     print i
... 
5
5 <generator object countdown at 0x1081e0e10>
4
4 <generator object countdown at 0x1081e0e60>
3
3 <generator object countdown at 0x1081e0eb0>
2
2 <generator object countdown at 0x1081e0f00>
1
1 <generator object countdown at 0x1081e0f50>
```

Here, the recursive calls returned a new generator object; if you wanted to have the *elements* produced by the generator your only choice is to loop over it and hand the elements down, not the generator object itself.

In Python 3, you can use `yield from` to *delegate* to a nested generator, including a recursive call:

```
def perms_generator(to_go, so_far=''):
    if not to_go:
        yield so_far
    else:
        for i, elem in enumerate(to_go):
            yield from perms_generator(to_go[:i] + to_go[i+1:], so_far + elem)
```

When encountering a `yield from` iteration continues into the recursive call instead of yielding the whole generator object.

Comment: is `so_far` a generator? We're returned this value and it would seem as though it is not a generator.

Comment: @gjdanis: no, the return value of `perms_generator` is.

Comment: How is `so_far` a generator object?

Comment: @gjdanis `so_far` isn't a generator object. It just gets returned (`yield`ed) by the generator object when you iterate over it. I highly recommend reading [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python?rq=1) to get a better idea of how `yield` works.